# Replace any beginning character instance with empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

Say I have a string like so:

```
let v = '/////bar/foo'
```

how can I just replace the slashes at the beginning of v with `''`?

I am looking to get this:

```
let result = 'bar/foo'
```

Comment: How do you define "*any beginning character instance*"? It seems you want to replace all non–alphabetic characters, which might be `/^[^a-z]+/i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let r = v.replace(/^\/+/, '');
```

The regular expression finds one or more `/` at the beginning of the string and replaces that pattern with `''`.

Answer (score 1):

A little regex and you're done:

```js
let v = '/////bar/foo';

console.log( v.replace(/^\/+/,'') );
```

- in `\/`, the `\` escapes the forward slash
- the `+` means 1 or more
- the `''` is the replacement string

Answer (score 0):

```
let parsed = v.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z\d]+/, '')
```

This will replace any character that is not alphanumeric

**or as pointed out by RobG**

```
/^\W+/
```

Comment: `/^\W+/` is shorter. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Oh fine :p